# how to activate html.dropdown on page load of mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("StatusType","Select a Value")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
    }
    <p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestHeading)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestDescription)
            </th>
```

Hope I am asking the right question. I am using entity framework in conjunction with MVC. Have used standard scaffolding with MVC controllers which results in the standard CRUD views.

I have altered the index  task in the controller to give me only those records matching my Windows authentication signin and those than have an'open' status type.

Code for controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string StatusType)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusitems = db.StatusTypes.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = c.Id == 1,
        Value = c.StatusTypeDescription,
        Text = c.StatusTypeDescription
    });
    ViewBag.StatusType = statusitems;
    var serviceRequests = db.ServiceRequests.Include(s => s.Category).Include(s => s.Member).Include(s => s.Priority).Include(s => s.RequestType).Include(s => s.RequestTypeStep).Include(s => s.StatusSet).Include(s => s.SubCategory).Include(s => s.TeamMember).Include(s => s.Team);
    //serviceRequests = serviceRequests.Where(s => s.RequestorID.Contains(User.Identity.Name));
    //serviceRequests = serviceRequests.Where(s => s.ServiceRequest_Status == 3 );
    serviceRequests = from sr in db.ServiceRequests
                      join ss in db.StatusSets on sr.ServiceRequest_Status equals ss.Id
                      join st in db.StatusTypes on ss.Status_StatusType equals st.Id
                      where sr.RequestorID.Contains(User.Identity.Name) & st.StatusTypeDescription== StatusType
                      select sr;

    return View(await serviceRequests.ToListAsync());
}
```

The controller loads statustypes into the select list item. C.Id==1 is 'Open' statustype.

In the view htnl I have the following code etc to populate dropdown:

It all works but the behavior is not exactly what I want.

What the view and controller does currently is ,it does default the html.dropdown to 'open' statustype. When I click the  filter button -INDEED it does filter the records in the table to be only the 'open' request records. And when I choose 'closed' on the html.dropdown it does choose only closed.

But if I don't click the filter button- no records show up in table.

WHAT I WANT is for the view to take the 'open' statustype I have correctly defaulted and use THAT and default populate the table when the view is loaded. In other words I want the view to load initially with the open records without having to click the filter button

View looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxnGp.jpg)

What am I missing here  -to have view initially load with default from the html.dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: You have not set a value for `StatusType` initially - check if its `null` and if so then set `StatusType = "Open"`. But then when you choose "Closed" in the view and submit, the returned view will display "Open: i the dropdown again! As always use a view model and strongly bind you view to the model using the `***For()` methods,

Comment: thanks. that worked